# Determining value of k (calculus)

Tags: calculus

For this question I know I have to take the derivative of the curve but do I equate it to the line to find k?

[image]

Comment: This kind of question is way easier if you draw a picture of the graph of $$\sqrt{x} + 2\sqrt{y} = 4$$ You can sketch lines with slope -1 too, if you want

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. Then find $dy/dx$ and set it equal to the slope of the tangent line (which will be -1).

$$\frac{dy}{dx}  = \frac{d}{dx}\left( -x + k\right) = -1$$

You should also draw a picture of the graph, it will make it easier to visually see what is going on, instead of just doing the algebra "blinded".